# Having trouble setting up redux-localstorage to work with existing store

Tags: local-storage, react-native, redux

I can't seem to setup the `redux-localstorage` module on `react-native`. I get an error message saying:

```
TypeError: (0, _reduxLocalstorage.mergePersistedState) is not a function. (In '(0, _reduxLocalstorage.mergePersistedState)()', '(0, _reduxLocalstorage.mergePersistedState)' is undefined)
```

Here is what my `configStore.jsx` file looks like. This is where I originally setup my redux store with `thunk` middleware. There aren't many examples online that show how to setup the redux-localstorage package! I'm not 100% sure how it works either. I'm only needing to store **1** object inside the localstorage, this is the user object. Which will hold the `api authentication key + user details`. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be amazing!

```
const local_storage_reducer = compose(
    mergePersistedState()
)(reducers);

const storage = compose(
  filter('user'),
  adapter(window.localStorage)
)
const createPersistentStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  persistState(storage),
)(createStore);


const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    persistState(storage, 'my-storage-key')
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStoreWithMiddleware(combineReducers(reducers));
}

export default function configurePersistentStore() {
    return createPersistentStore(reducers);
}
```

Here is how I inject the store to my components via the `provider` component.

```
const store = configureStore();
const persistentStore = configurePersistentStore();
<Provider store={[store,persistentStore] }>
       .... Router stuff here ....
```

I'm not sure if this is remotely how you setup the `redux-localstorage` or whether I'm on the right track and have made a small mistake.

Comment: window.localStorage doesn't exist in React Native. Look at [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Buchea pointed out you can't use localStorage on React Native, so AsyncStorage is the way out.

redux-localstorage already have an [adapter](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage/tree/1.0-breaking-changes#adapters) for that:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
import adapter from 'redux-localstorage/lib/adapters/AsyncStorage';

const storage = adapter(AsyncStorage);
```